How can I optimize search in small fixed size array?
I'd like to find the first occurrence of a byte in a 16-byte array. If I write a naive version (either using iterators or with a manual loop), rustc doesn't appear to vectorize (https://godbolt.org/z/fbKfvxTdv).
My vague idea of an optimized solution would be something like

broadcast x into some vector register
compare it with every element of y at once
collect the 16 resulting bools into a u16
do something with count_leading_zeros to find which one matched.

Instead, for the manual loop, it's simply unrolled fully with 16 comparisons and jumps, and for the iterator-based version, it doesn't seem to be taking advantage of the known fixed length (exactly 16) at all
pub fn find_first(x: u8, y: &[u8;16]) -> Option<usize> {
    y.iter().position(|w| *w == x)
}

pub fn find_first_manual(x: u8, y: &[u8;16]) -> Option<usize> {
    for i in 0..16 {
        if y[i] == x {
            return Some(i);
        }
    }
    None
}


Since the size is fixed and very small, does it make sense to optimize it? If you do, remember with such a small, fixed size the normal time complexity goes out the window. Those constants we normally drop now matter.

A jump table is about as fast as you can get: just cmp and jmp, and it can exit immediately upon finding the first one. Your proposal always cmps every element, has to allocate a u16, and has to scan that u16. If you want to "compare it with every element of y at once" that requires spanning a very, very simple operation across multiple cores which adds overhead.

@Schwern it just requires SIMD, which has next to no overhead

In nightly exists the Portable SIMD module, which is very convenient.
Please find below an attempt to realise the algorithm you suggested, as well as the disassembled version from the compiler explorer, and a benchmark showing that, at least on my computer, the SIMD version you suggested is beneficial.
#![feature(test)] // cargo bench
#![feature(portable_simd)]

pub fn find_first(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8; 16],
) -> Option<usize> {
    y.iter().position(|w| *w == x)
}

pub fn find_first_manual(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8; 16],
) -> Option<usize> {
    for i in 0..16 {
        if y[i] == x {
            return Some(i);
        }
    }
    None
}

pub fn find_first_simd(
    x: u8,
    y: &[u8; 16],
) -> Option<usize> {
    use std::simd::cmp::SimdPartialEq;
    use std::simd::u8x16;
    let x = u8x16::splat(x);
    let y = u8x16::from_array(*y);
    let e = x.simd_eq(y);
    e.first_set()
}
/*
in https://godbolt.org/
rustc nightly with options
  -C opt-level=3 -C target-feature=+avx -C target-feature=+avx2
gives

example::find_first_simd::hd89fd3b592dbfe03:
        vmovd   xmm0, edi
        vpbroadcastb    xmm0, xmm0
        vpcmpeqb        xmm0, xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        vpmovmskb       ecx, xmm0
        xor     eax, eax
        test    ecx, ecx
        setne   al
        rep       bsf edx, ecx
        ret
*/

fn main() {
    let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    for x in [0, 4, 9] {
        println!("first({}) {:?}", x, find_first(x, &y));
        println!("first_manual({}) {:?}", x, find_first_manual(x, &y));
        println!("first_simd({}) {:?}", x, find_first_simd(x, &y));
    }
}
/*
first(0) Some(0)
first_manual(0) Some(0)
first_simd(0) Some(0)
first(4) Some(4)
first_manual(4) Some(4)
first_simd(4) Some(4)
first(9) None
first_manual(9) None
first_simd(9) None
*/

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    extern crate test; // not in Cargo.toml

    const REPEAT: usize = 1000;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_find_first_simd(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            for _ in 0..REPEAT {
                let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
                for x in [0, 4, 9] {
                    test::black_box(find_first_simd(
                        test::black_box(x),
                        test::black_box(&y),
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_find_first(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            for _ in 0..REPEAT {
                let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
                for x in [0, 4, 9] {
                    test::black_box(find_first(
                        test::black_box(x),
                        test::black_box(&y),
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_find_first_manual(b: &mut test::Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            for _ in 0..REPEAT {
                let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
                for x in [0, 4, 9] {
                    test::black_box(find_first_manual(
                        test::black_box(x),
                        test::black_box(&y),
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
/*
test tests::bench_find_first        ... bench:       4,282 ns/iter (+/- 74)
test tests::bench_find_first_manual ... bench:       4,246 ns/iter (+/- 45)
test tests::bench_find_first_simd   ... bench:       2,716 ns/iter (+/- 45)
*/


Your idea mentioned in the question makes sense.
Alternatively, it can be done with _mm_cmpestrc/_mm_cmpestri.
If the compiler doesn't do it for you, even with hints, as in find_first_manual, you can do it manually by using SSE / AVX intrinsics.
Library functions like C standard memchr, are usually optimized already, although if they stay in the library and not inlined to your code by the compiler, they cannot take advantage of the known context, which is in your case length of 16 assumption. Don't know if Rust has memchr.

Rust does not have memchr builtin, but as usual when "search through stuff quickly" is involved burntsushi provides.

As burntsushi explains (amongst heaps of other stuff), the stdlib already uses SSE, however it's limited to SSE2 for compatibility reasons (runtime CPU feature detection is not supported in core yet).

For 16 elements as in question there's no big difference between SSE2 and AVX2, as 16 bytes fit SSE register, and all needed ops are available in SSE2 (except that broadcast would take few instructions)
